# result decimal value with comma c#

Tags: c#

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string value = TextBox.Text.Replace(",", "");
    long ul;
    if (long.TryParse(value, out ul))
    {
        TextBox.TextChanged -= TextBoxTextChanged;
        TextBox.Text = string.Format("{0:#,#0}", ul);
        TextBox.SelectionStart = TextBox.Text.Length;
        TextBox.TextChanged += TextBoxTextChanged;
    }
}
```

I used above code. I can type `1,234.1234` but if I press `1,000.123 + 1,000.123` it does not give result `2,000.246` - it give result only `2000.246`. I mean comma not giving.

Can anybody kindly please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: I suggest to edit the question title being the real question.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to the bottom of your function:

```
TextBox.TextChanged = String.Format("{0:#,###0}");
```

That will give you commas on thousands places on the last result of the textbox (after the calculations).

Comment: Sorry Sir, this code in not giving my proper result.

Comment: what is your result?

Comment: It gives me 1,000.123 + 1,000.123 = 2000.246 but I need result 2,000.246